# Ionic1 store function show login page after login continue the store operation

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I'm writing a function about add something to my shopping cart,when you click add button,if you are not login,the login page shown,login page was written like `$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl`, after people input there username and password, `$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl` has a `doLogin` function, when people login,I want to continue add things to the shopping cart,but I can only come back to the add page.Someone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: here is my service code
angular.module('service', [])
    .factory('ModalService', function($q, $rootScope, $ionicModal){
        var _login = function(fromState) {
            var param = {};
            if (!$scope.loginmodal) {
                $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', {
                    scope: $scope
                }).then(function(modal) {
                    $scope.loginmodal.show();
                    $scope.doLogin = function(Authkey) { } else {
                $scope.loginmodal.show();
            }
        return {
        login: _login

Comment: Edit question with it.